# How to build the LAPACK in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, cmake, java-native-interface, lapack, cmakelists-options

Currently, I have an Android Project in which I am using the JNI(Java native interface) to call the LAPACK C function.

**My JNI is:**

**native-lib.c**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "lapack/LAPACKE/include/lapack.h"
#include "lapack/LAPACKE/example/lapacke_example_aux.h"
 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_lapacktest_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject obj /* this */) {
    char hello[20] = "Hello from C++";
     double A[5][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,1},{3,5,2},{4,1,4},{2,5,3}};
     double b[5][2] = {{-10,12},{14,16},{18,-3},{14,12},{16,16}};
     lapack_int info,m,n,lda,ldb,nrhs;

     /* Initialization */
     m = 5;
     n = 3;
     nrhs = 2;
     lda = 5;
     ldb = 5;

     /* Print Entry Matrix */
     print_matrix_colmajor( "Entry Matrix A", m, n, *A, lda );

  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,hello);
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
project(LapackTest)
add_library( native-lib
        SHARED
        native-lib.c
        #lapack/LAPACKE/example/lapacke_example_aux.c
        )

# Add dependent libraries
add_library(blas STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET blas PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libblas.a)

add_library(lapack STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET lapack PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/liblapack.a)


# Location of header files
include_directories(
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lapack/BLAS
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lapack/CBLAS
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lapack/LAPACKE
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lapack/SRC
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lapack/TESTING
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lapack/CBLAS
)

add_subdirectory(lapack)
```

The problem is when I try to call the function print_matrix_colmajor() which is present inside the lapack directory then it gives us undefined reference issue. I want to make my CMakeList in such a way that i could be able to call any lapack function from my JNI.
Can someone help me to build the lapack module using the CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: You create IMPORTED library targets `blas` and `lapack`, but I don't see in your code a place, where you **link** with these targets.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  I can't figure out how to link these. Can you give me some example for that. Your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Linking with a library is performed with `target_link_libraries` command. E.g. if you want to link your `native-lib` library with the lapack, then you could use `target_link_libraries(native-lib PUBLIC lapack)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have also tried target_link_libraries command but that gives me error that 

**The Ninja generator does not support Fortran using Ninja version

    1.8.2

  due to lack of required features.  Kitware has implemented the required
  features but as of this version of CMake they have not been integrated to
  upstream ninja**